# c# wpf - wrong dir for images but video works ok

Tags: c#, wpf, image, path

i've created WPF C# project in Visual Studio 2k15 and I've placed 2 files in X directory, so my dir looks like:

```
app.exe
X->1.mp4,2.png
```

When i'm selecting dir for mediaelement (video), it works fine

```
<MediaElement x:Name="backgroundvideo" Source="X\1.mp4" IsMuted="True"/>
```

But when i'm selecting dir for my imageelement (image) it says:

```
Could not find file (path to vs main folder)
```

And my imageelement looks like this:

```
<Image x:Name="login_ico_png" Source="x/2.png" Margin="120,50,120,422"  
                            Stretch="Fill" Width="128" Height="128"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<Image x:Name="login_ico_png" Source="ms-appx:///x/2.png" Margin="120,50,120,422"  
                            Stretch="Fill" Width="128" Height="128"/>
```